# best software to allow java/eclipse development across multiple machines

Tags: software-development, file-synchronization

I would like to setup a couple different computers such that I can pick up where I left off as far as development of software - I typically use windows/eclipse/java, but solutions that would work on a broader scope would be welcome as well.

I currently use Dropbox for the workspace, but it's a pain to ignore certain files (like the .lock files), and the eclipse settings themselves don't sync (unless I were to move the entire Eclipse folder into Dropbox, which seems silly..)

I know there exist lots of source control systems, and I already use them, but I am looking for something that will keep them synced without it becoming a PITA for me to check out/in, write comments, etc. each time (and I generally only check stuff in once it works.. but I may switch computers before I get it to work)

Comment: How about making git auto-commit with inotifywait (indeed then you still have to check out), or rsync?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [mecurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) as a VCS and adding the [eclipse plugin](http://javaforge.com/project/HGE) for it - the committing and pushing will just be a couple of clicks.

You can have multiple repositories with mercurial so if you clone your work repository - (this can be done even if it is SVN/git/some others) - to your work machine.

Do your work on a branch so commits of unfinished work don't pollute the trunk/default and merge when ready - with histedit you can even collapse merges down prior to doing your merge to the main code.

Comment: any way to make it more automatic so I don't have to remember to "commit" it at all (like auto-save basically), or commit each save? and ideally also to update as soon as I launch the editor

Comment: IIRC Eclipse is highly customisable, presumably you exit it before leaving for work/home, you could probably have it auto-commit on exit and auto-pull on start-up. Just be sure it is not doing so to a production repository!